# Is Azure system uuid immutable over the VM lifetime?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, uuid

We are looking a system UUID as a license locking criteria, and from what I can see it should work. But I can't find a definitive answer on whether the UUID survives changing availability zones/regions, changing vm size, restoring from backup etc.

Are there any corner cases where the UUID will change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one situation in which it will change:

> Azure Unique VM ID won’t change upon reboot, shutdown (either planned
> for unplanned), start/stop de-allocate, service healing or restore in
> place. **However, if the VM is a snapshot and copied to create a new
> instance, Azure VM ID will get changed.**

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/nb-no/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/

Comment: Thank you, that was what we needed to hear.

Comment: Can you accept and upvote the answer if it answered your question